# Jquery-turbolinks gem not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, jquery-rails

I am using the jquery-turbolinks gem so that

```
$(document).ready()
```

gets fired every page load even when rails turbolinks is turned on. I followed the steps on the [github page](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) to install the gem, but the gem doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's what I've done so far:

1. added `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`
2. added `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to my javascript manifest file. My manifest file now looks like this:

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.turbolinks
   //= require_tree .
   //= require turbolinks

   $(document).ready(function() {
       alert("turbo!");
   });
   ```
3. Then I killed and restarted the rails server

I ran a basic rails scaffold to test to see if everything would work, and I only saw the alert pop up when the application initially loads. However, when I navigated from the index action to the show action, I didn't see the alert box pop up.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

Comment: Can you run bundle show turbolinks too what version you're using

Comment: after running bundle update, it says I'm using turbolinks version 5.0.0. I'm using rails 4.2.6

Comment: Ill post my suggestion holp on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this problem occurs because some of the key events in turbolinks 5 have changed. I fixed this problem by downloading the compatibility script suggested by turbolinks. You can find the script [here](https://github.com/mrvncaragay/HyraV2/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/compatibility.coffee) just create a compatibility.coffee under 'assets/javascripts'